# Qt - Access a checkbox in a table

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I have a table and each row in the table has a checkbox in it's first column. I need to make it so I can detect which checkboxes are checked and delete those rows when a button is pressed.

```
QWidget * chkWidget = new QWidget();
QHBoxLayout *center = new QHBoxLayout();
center->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );
center->addWidget( new QCheckBox );
chkWidget->setLayout( center );
ui->data_table->setCellWidget(rowCount,0, chkWidget);
```

Was this done right? If so how do I access the checkboxes at each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talk about a QTableWidget. You can use a QList.You save your QCheckBox into this QList and use it, when there is some change

Maybe you should check out the documentation

- QTableWidget: [Link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qtablewidget.html)
- QList: [Link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html)

Here is a solution. I cannot run it at the moment, so please tell me if it works. Please validate the row value. I am not sure if it's possible, that row can have the value -1 when you delete the last row ;)

```
#include "TestTableWidget.h"
#include "ui_TestTableWidget.h"

TestTableWidget::TestTableWidget(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::TestTableWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    tableWidget = new QTableWidget(this);
    tableWidget->setColumnCount(1); // Just an example

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(tableWidget);

    connect(tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(slotChange()));

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        addRow("Row " + QString::number(i));
    }
}

TestTableWidget::~TestTableWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TestTableWidget::addRow(QString text)
{
    int row = tableWidget->rowCount();
    qDebug() << "Current row count is " + QString::number(row);

    // Add new one
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(text);
    tableWidget->insertRow(row);
    tableWidget->setItem(row, 0, item);

    // Add item to our list
}

void TestTableWidget::slotChange()
{
    int row = tableWidget->currentRow();
    qDebug() << "Change in table. Current row-index: " + QString::number(row);
    // This value is zero-based, so you can use it in our list
}
```